# Create a object by tranfsorming list of object to string and int array by using linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am trying to select the columns from a database and then create a single array property of each column, and create a single object.

```
public class Activity
{
    public string[] Quiz { get; set; }
    public int[] CompletedCount { get; set; }
}
```

The database output from the results will be returned as:

```
IQueryable<QuizCompletedCount> results = _logContext.QuizCompletedCounts;
```

I have got the value from the database in the following format.

```
Week        | Completed
---------------------------
Week 1      |   107
Week 2      |   104
Week 3      |   87
Week 4      |   49
Week 5      |   6
```

I tried in this way:

```
List<int> activityCount = new List<int>();
List<string> activity = new List<string>();

foreach (var element in results)
{
    activity.Add(element.Week);
    activityCount.Add(element.Completed);
}

var obj = new QuizActivity();
obj.CompletedCount = activityCount.ToArray();
obj.Week = activity.ToArray();
```

Desired Output will look like:

```
string str = "{\"Week\":[\"Week 1\",\"Week 2\",\"Week 3\",\"Week 4\",\"Week 5\"],\"CompletedCount\":[107,104,87,49,6]}";
```

Is there `linq` approach for doing this task without using `foreach` and multiple conversion from list to array?

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like that:

```
var result = new QuizActivity()
{
    Week = results.Select(x => x.Week).ToList(),
    CompletedCount = results.Select(x => x.Completed).ToList()
};
```

Comment: may be `.ToArray()`?

Comment: Yeah, as you wish.